# Approximating the exponent of a matrix $\exp(A)$ using Taylor series

Tags: matrix

I am trying to approximate the exponential of a matrix. I want to use a tolerance but I am confused as to how to compute the error. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what do you mean by tolerance, is it a relative/absolute error in the matrix norm?

Comment: i am trying to use scaling and squaring but I find it had to incorporate the tolerance into it. It is a relative error, next term in the Taylor series mines the previous. I think that is what you mean with relative/absolute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First: there is a must read on this topic

> Moler, Cleve, and Charles Van Loan. "[Nineteen dubious ways to compute the exponential of a matrix, twenty-five years later](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/researchpdf/19ways+.pdf)." SIAM review 45.1 (2003): 3-49.

(in case you wonder, the original paper is

> Moler, Cleve, and Charles Van Loan. "Nineteen dubious ways to compute the exponential of a matrix." SIAM review 20.4 (1978): 801-836.)

More to the question: The following error bound from [this slides](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/exp10.pdf) will be helpful:

For a complex  $n\times n$ matrix $A$ let
$$
T_{r,s} = \Big(\sum_{i=0}^r \frac{1}{i!}\big(\tfrac{A}{s}\big)^i\Big)^s
$$
then
$$
\|e^A - T_{r,s}\| \leq \frac{\|A\|^{r+1}}{s^r(r+1)!}e^{\|A\|}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I have not entirely thought this through, but have you have thought about using the largest eigenvalue?
If $A$ is your matrix, and $Q \Lambda Q^{-1}$ its eigendecomposition, then you can use the following identity for each term in your Taylor series:
\begin{equation}
A^n = Q \Lambda^n Q^{-1} \quad .
\end{equation}
Then, you take the largest eigenvalue, and compute from it an upper bound for the Lagrange remainder.
Obviously, this works best for symmetric matrices where Q is orthogonal.
But I still think this may be a good starting point.